# How std::cin.get(c) sets c when the input is EOF?

Tags: c++, eof

From my experience I should not assign the return value that is `int` from `std::getchar`, `std::cin.get()`, `std::cin.peek()` to a `char` because it is so dangerous and error-prone.

- So I can use: `std::cin.get(c);` but not `c = std::cin.get()`.

Now if I issue this:

```
char ch;
std::cin.get(ch); // Ctrl+D
```

And the user enters the end of file `EOF` (-1) how does the function `std::cin.get(c)` set it to `ch`? or `ch` has the value `\0`? Thank you.

Comment: Any non-null return value from **cin** is valid. So, yes NULL return is EOF.

Comment: @moi That is not correct.  `EOF` is returned on EOF and `EOF` *Returns a value not equivalent to any valid value of type char_type.*

Comment: EOF gives a negative return value, a NULL return value for error and any positive return value implies success for cin. @NathanOliver is that correct ?

Comment: @moi Nope.  `EOF` is returned on any error.

Answer (score 2):

Please learn to read documentation:

[std::basic_istream<CharT,Traits>::get - cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get)

> 2. Reads one character and stores it to `ch` if available. **Otherwise, leaves `ch` unmodified** and sets [failbit](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/iostate) and [eofbit](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/iostate). Note that this function is not overloaded on the types signed char and unsigned char, unlike the formatted character input operator>>.

Answer (score 2):

From https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get :

> basic_istream& get( char_type& ch );
> (2)
>
> (2) Reads one character and stores it to ch if available. Otherwise, leaves ch unmodified and sets failbit and eofbit.

> How std::cin.get(c) sets c when the input is EOF?

The function does not set it in such case.

> I can use: std::cin.get(c); but not c = std::cin.get().

You still can use it. Just check stream status.

```
char c;
if (!std::cin.get(c)) {
     std::cout << "You typed EOF!\n";
} else {
     std::cout << "You typed: " << c << '\n';
}
```

> how does the function std::cin.get(c) set it to ch?

It doesn't, it does not modify `c` in such case.

> ch has the value \0?

In case of `EOF`, in your code `ch` is left uninitialized, so it has "indeterminate" value. It could be `'\0'`, could be any other value.